# New instance declaration for Show with a list

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to haskell and i have the task of defining a new instance declaration for Show for the data types i defined but i'm struggling. I've been searching through the already answered questions in here but i'm not getting anywhere and it's been so frustrating that i created an account just to get this over with.

Imagine i have declared two new data types like this,

```
data shoppingList = shoppingList { name :: String
                                 , items :: [Item]}
data Item = Food String Float | Clothes String
```

I need to make an instance declaration of Show so that any shoppingList will look something like `name: dog_food -> CLOTHES -> many_apples -> CLOTHES`, depending on wether it's Food or Clothes. This means, if it's Food, it prints the name that was given to the food, if it's Clothes, it just prints "CLOTHES" every time.

The best i managed to do is,

```
instance Show shoppingList where
  show (shoppingList n l) = show n ++ ": " ++ show l

instance Show Item where
  show (Food n _) = show n
  show (Clothes_) = "CLOTHES"
```

However, this isn't the final result i'm looking for since it's printing something like `"list1": ["dog_food",CLOTHES,"many_apples",CLOTHES]` and this is not what i need.

The example might look a bit stupid but it shows my big question. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to abuse `Show` instances like this because `Show` is supposed to produce a string representation of a data structure that's as close as possible to the way you'd write the data structure manually in Haskell source code.  Or was this a homework problem where you *had* to use a `Show` instance?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr it's a homework problem where i have to use that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you've already got the part to the left of the colon; all you need is the part to the right.

As you've noted, `show` doesn't do what you want — that means you've got to do this string manipulation bit yourself.

This particular task (intercalating strings in a list with something) can easily be one using `intercalate` from `Data.List` (documented [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate)).

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
```

Then, your instance declaration for `ShoppingList` (note the capital S) would be as follows:

```hs
instance Show ShoppingList where
    show (ShoppingList n l) = show n ++ ": " ++ intercalate " -> " (map show l)
```

As a side note, it's counter-intuitive (at least for me) that `name` would be a `Float` and not a `String` (or similar). You should probably consider changing that.

Comment: Thank you so much, you unblocked me from moving forward in this work! I can't thank enough! And you are right about the name being better as a `String` than as a `Float`, but this was just an example i came up with since what i _needed_ to know was how to present the list like that. Thank you!

Comment: @stanloona Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to capitalize the initial letters of the type and value constructors ;)

```
import Data.List

data ShoppingList = ShoppingList { name :: String
                                 , items :: [Item]}

data Item = Food String Float | Clothes String

instance Show Item where
  show (Food a _) = a
  show (Clothes _) = "CLOTHES"

instance Show ShoppingList where
  show a = let listName = name a
               listItems = intercalate " -> " (map show $ items a)
               in listName ++ ": " ++ listItems

-- use "show yourShoppingListName" to let the magic happen^^"
```